# Using Metal API in background thread on macOS

Tags: multithreading, metal

my code calculates parts (tiles) of the final image on concurrent threads within CGContext. I need to pass the partial result of each calculation (vertex data) within a thread to the GPU for rendering by using MPSImageGaussianBlur. After that, I create the final bitmap from the resulting MTLTexture and draw it back to CGContext and the original thread. All render passes, on every thread, utilize a common commandQueue (created on the main thread). Each render pass initiates and terminates within the same thread. Other threads do not require access to resources from other threads/render passes as all data are isolated within their respective threads. However, I'm uncertain how to call Metal API ( encode commands, etc.) from threads other than the main thread in this circumstance. Despite this, I cannot modify the way I calculate vertex data (in concurrent threads). Do you have any advice on how to carry out this task securely? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the command queue is created. The methods of command queue are thread safe, which means you can create a command buffer and fill it out on a background thread an then commit it.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the even though APIs on `MTLDevice`, `MTLCommandQueue` are safe, the APIs on `MTLCommandBuffer` and everything below, so any command encoder, are not thread safe. So basically, you can give each thread a command buffer, but you can't give a single command buffer to more than one thread. The only exception here is parallel render command encoders.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy please post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MTLCommandQueue` in multiple threads. It doesn't matter where the command queue is created. The methods of command queue are thread safe, which means you can create a command buffer and fill it out on a background thread and then commit it. You can either `enqueue` your `MTLCommandBuffers` before giving them away to a background thread, if the command buffers need to go in a specific order. Or you can just `commit` them as they are ready.

Keep in mind, that the even though APIs on MTLDevice, MTLCommandQueue are safe, the APIs on MTLCommandBuffer and everything below, so any command encoder, are not thread safe. So basically, you can give each thread a command buffer, but you can't give a single command buffer to more than one thread. The only exception here is parallel render command encoders, which let you create "sub-encoders", that you can then also share between multiple threads.

Comment: Can you please advise also on the usage of MTLBlitCommandEncoder in the same scenario? I am using a shared MTLBuffer for vertex data (usually over 4kb) that is created in every render pass for every thread. Is it possible to create a pre-allocated MTLBuffer (128k), copy vertex data that is over 4kb but less than 128kb to this buffer, and potentially use MTLBlitCommandEncoder to copy the data from the shared buffer to a private buffer (ifI know the data will not change and will be accessed frequently)?